# Azure Service Bus: How to enable Enforced Message Ordering on a partitioned queue?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

After our solution has gone into production we find out that we need the option `Enforced Message Ordering`. The queue is partitioned (for redundancy apparently).

If I try to switch the `Enforced Message Ordering` option on, I get the following error:

> For a Partitioned Queue, ordering is supported only if RequiresSession
>   is set to true.

The `Requires Session` option is disabled (and I wouldn't want to change it in production any way without testing it first).

How should I proceed? I don't think we need Partitioning, but I'm in the dark if we can switch that on or off. If it is possible to enable `Requires Session` that would be an option (after testing and maybe making some code changes), but is switching `Requires Session` possible at all?

Are we doomed to change our code to make it independent of the order, or otherwise set up a whole new Service bus and get all parties to switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partitioned queue is a queue that has 16 broker instances services messages. Enforcing order on a partitioned queue will be practically impossible. That's why you get the error.

Enabling [Message Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions) is not just ticking another box, unfortunately. It means changing how your code works, both for sending and receiving side. Message sessions enforce ordered message delivery and require a slightly different approach where messages around bound by a session ID. It also means that you cannot scale out the processing of the messages that belong to the same session.

> Are we doomed to change our code to make it independent of the order, or otherwise set up a whole new Service bus and get all parties to switch?

I would suggest analyzing the requirement to have ordered messaging and see if you **really** need it. Messaging and order don't mix well. In some cases, when the order it truly needed, sessions with Azure Service Bus is the way to go, but it requires a very specific way of working with those.

Another option to handle messages arriving out of order with a need to coordinate work is to implement a pattern such as a Coordinator/[Process Manager](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/ProcessManager.html) or Saga. Libraries such as [NServiceBus](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/) and [MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/sagas/) offer saga implementation you can have a look at.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up that sessions is not an option. Would it be possible to transform the queue to a non-partitioned queue? Ordering is really needed, the messages contain some state information and currently the last state wins... The coordinator / manager / Saga options you mention really look like an overkill in our situation, it would be easier to alter the application than introduce a service in the middle. I guess setting up a new service bus may be a better option after all if reconfiguring is not possible...

Comment: Once a queue with partitioning is deployed it cannot be changed back to non-partitioned w/o deleting and redeploying it. Premium tier doesn't have partitioning, but that would mean dealing with migration and a higher cost. You might just replace the queues if it's possible.